# TypeScript - jasmine - Chutzpah - AMD - Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, jasmine, amd, chutzpah

I can't get testing of TypeScript in VS using jasmine/Chutzpah to work with AMD.

Sample.ts:

```
export class Sample {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}
```

Simple.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./jasmine.d.ts" />

import SampleModule = module("./Sample");

describe("TypeScript1", function () {
    it("should pass a simple test", function () {
          expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });
});

describe("TypeScript2", function () {
    it("should pass a sample test", function () {
        var sample = new SampleModule.Sample("Wow");
            expect(sample.name).toEqual("Wow");
    });
});
```

...this results in:

Test Name:  TypeScript1 should pass a simple test
Test Outcome:   Passed

Test Name:  TypeScript2 should pass a sample test
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00

Result Message: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SampleModule in file:typescripthtmlapp1/_Chutzpah.28.simple.js (line 9)

Adding:

```
/// <reference path="./Sample.ts" />
```

...results in no detected tests.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is that the Javascript module loader (require.js) is not included by Chutzpah when running the test, and so the module does not load - hence the error.

See change request [here](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/workitem/93) - apparently the solution will be to add something like this in the test file:

```
///<chutzpah_reference path="../scripts/require.js" />
```

<s>but the fix is not available yet</s>.

**UPDATE**

The fix should be available in Chutzpah version 2.4.

Comment: what you mean with "chutzpah_reference" ? I am getting same problem trying run Qunit Tests using chutzpah addin.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464984/how-to-load-a-public-function-using-qunit-and-typescript

Comment: The author of Chutzpath added the handling of a 'chutzpah_reference' tag to specify JavaScript files that need to be included when running the test - see the link referred by 'here' in my answer.

Comment: @MiMo, I have installed Chutzpah 2.4 and added the ///<chutzpah_reference path, but still can't get it to work.
Anything more that I need to do?

Comment: @user2144887: the ticket concerning that issue said that the fix was made, but not released at that time - did you check if the fix is supposed to be in 2.4?

Comment: @user2144887: sorry, no idea - I did not try it (yet) myself, so I cannot even tell you for sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Chutzpah does not currently support TypeScript files which generate AMD code. I had experimented with this a couple releases ago but ran into issues with how TypeScript generated its output.

I plan to revisit this in a future release and I file [this item to track](https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/workitem/122) the state of this work.

Could you visit that item and attach a zip of your sample so I can be sure that my fix correctly addresses your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find working sample with TypeScript - jasmine - Chutzpah - AMD - Visual Studio 2012:
http://chrisseroka.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/javascripttypescript-unit-testing-11-sample-projects-for-resharper-chutzpah-and-karma/